# What is the best approach to use cache in Django?

Tags: python, django, caching

I have a `GET` and `POST` request in a `Django APIView`.

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework import status
    
class DemoView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        user_id = request.query_params.get('user_id', None)
        num = MyModel.objects.get(id=user_id).num
        for i in range(num):
            num = num*i + 1. # In real work, much more complicated.
        return Response({'success': True, 'square':num}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
   
    def post(self, request):
        user_id = request.data.get('user_id', None)
        num = request.data.get('num', None)
        num_from_my_model =  MyModel.objects.get(id=user_id).num
        if num == num_from_my_model:
            MyModel.objects.filter(id=user_id).update(num=num) 
        return Response({'success': True}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

The problem is in my real work, `GET` method may need a long time(about 10 seconds) to finish. Here is how I do it:

(1) First of all, I create a database `MyCache` to see if `num` has changed in `POST` method.

(2) If changed, `MyCache` will turn the `cache_changed` parameter to True(default False).

(3) In `GET` method, I will check if `cache_changed` is True. If True, I will save result into cache. If False, I will get result from cache.

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework import status
from django.core.cache import cache
    
class DemoView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        user_id = request.query_params.get('user_id', None)
        cache_changed = MyCache.objects.get(id=user_id).cache_changed
        if not cache_changed and cache.has_key('result'):
           num = cache.get('result')
        else:
           num = MyModel.objects.get(id=user_id).num
           for i in range(num):
               num = num*i + 1.
           cache.set('result', num, 100)
        return Response({'success': True, 'result':num}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
   
    def post(self, request):
        user_id = request.data.get('user_id', None)
        num = request.data.get('num', None)
        num_from_my_model =  MyModel.objects.get(id=user_id).num
        if num == num_from_my_model:
            MyModel.objects.filter(id=user_id).update(num=num)
            MyCache.objects.filter(id=user_id).update(cache_changed=True)    
        return Response({'success': True}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

As far as I am concerned, if two or more `GET` request is sent, the second or the later can be responsed more quickly. As I am very new to cache, Here I have two questions:

(1) I don't know if this is the best approach for this kind of task.

(2) Can I add a very long time to save the result in cache, for example `cache.set('result', num, 10*24*60*60)`

It will be my great pleasure if anyone can give me a suggestion.

Comment: What about Redis Cache?

Comment: @TanveerAhmad Yeah I use Redis as the cache backend.

Comment: this is first time i got request when i hit my api 
[Mon Mar 28 2022 12:49:30 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)] INFO Requests per second: 1320
2nd time when i hit this api i got 1417 request per second

Comment: @TanveerAhmad I have tested in my real work, it works well. The second request is about 15s, and the second request is about 60ms.

Comment: It should be great if you cache the value on the other layer, for example on nginx.